# How to Create search function in Flask using Sqlite3

Tags: html, sqlite, flask

This is my form for search function

```
  <form class="form-inline ml-auto" action="{{ url_for('search') }}" method="POST">
<input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" name="search" id="search">
<button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
```

> Now I wan to display it if its match so this is my html

```
      {% for articles in data %}
  <div class="card m-3">
    <input type="hidden" value="{{ data[0] }}" id="id" name="id">
    <h5 class="card-header">{{ data[0] }}</h5>
    <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">{{ data[2] }} - {{ data[3] }}</h5>
        <p class="card-text">{{ data[4] }}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row m-3 ml-auto">
        <div class="btn-group mr-2">
          <a href="/edit/{{articles.id}}" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Update Article</a>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group">
            <a href="/{{articles.id}}" class="btn btn-outline-danger">Delete Article</a>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
```

> And also this is my query filter

```
    @app.route('/search',methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def search_route():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            q= request.args.get('search')
            with sqlite3.connect("blogdb.db") as con:
                cur = con.cursor()
                cur.execute('SELECT * FROM articles WHERE title = ?', (q))
                art = cur.fetchall()
                cur.close()
                print(art[0])
                con.commit()
            return render_template('search.html', data = art[0])
```

> So far what I got is that it doesnt return anything I also tried to `print(art[0])` so that I can see what did i get but i aint getting anything.

Comment: If you run the query manually (with sqlite3.exe on windows, or something else) do you get results? You probably don't need con.commit() for just a select query..

Comment: Nope im not getting any valeus in `print(art[0])` and Also the `q` doest have value i think i need to pass the values parameters